# Calculate automatically the degree of rotation of an element in a 3d carousel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, carousel

I want to make a 3d carousel that takes the information from the data base and calculates itself the degree of rotation of every attribute according to the number of elements received from the data base.
I have limited the number of elements that can be called in the carousel to 6.
But in my css everything is written and divided by 6 so if I have only 3 elements in the data base, there are 3 three turns that are blank.
I am a student and I started coding this year. I work with Twig.
Here is my twig file:

```
<div class="containerc">
  <div class="carousel1">
    {% for ev in events %}
      <div class="item1">
        <a href="?page=evenements&id_events={{ ev.id_events }}">
          <img src="images/{{ ev.photo }}" width="100%" height="auto" alt="{{ ev.alt }}">
        </a>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="prev">Prev</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<script src="JS/carousel.js"></script>
```

And this is the css:

```
.containerc {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 12vh;
  margin-bottom: 19vh;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;

}


.item1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.item1:nth-child(1)  {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: transparent;
}
.item1:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: transparent;
}
.item1:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: transparent;
}
.item1:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: transparent;
}
.item1:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: transparent;
}
.item1:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: transparent;
}
```

And the Java Script file:

```
  var carousel = $(".carousel1"),
  currdeg  = 0;

$(".next").on("click", { d: "n" }, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", { d: "p" }, rotate);

function rotate(e){
  if(e.data.d=="n"){
    currdeg = currdeg - 60;
  }
  if(e.data.d=="p"){
    currdeg = currdeg + 60;
  }
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)"
  });
}
```

I have searched how to do that but I couldn't find anything.
Is there a way to do it with css?
If not, I suppose I should do it with Java Script, but I can't see how and if done with Java Script probably I should change everything in the css.

Comment: You could change the carousel class based on the number of items taken from the database (carousel6, carousel5, etc) and then target each possibility in your css. It's probably simpler and cleaner to just use js though.

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, it would be probably cleaner wit Java Script, but I can't see how to do it-it won't be simpler for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, didn't notice you were using jQuery (brainfart). Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initApplication();//DOM is ready to be edited
});
//set up our page
    function initApplication(){
        var items = $('.carousel1 .item1');//gets an array of each element with the "item1" class contained in a container with the "carousel1" class
        var numItems = items.length;//gets the number of items in the array
        var increment = 360/numItems;//gets the increment in degrees (60 for 6 items, 120 for 3, etc)

        //loop through each element in the array
        for(var i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
            //apply the increment to each element. example output for 6 items: 0,60,120,180,240,300
            items.eq(i).css("transform", "rotateY(" + (i*increment) + "deg) translateZ(250px)");
        }
    }

        //rest of js
```

This will override any css you have and it might behave a bit weird at 7 items or any other number than doesn't divide nicely into 360. Basically all we're doing is applying the transforms as inline style via js when the page is ready for the js to edit it.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zLrb5a1/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the code and explanations! I see the logic.
The thing is when I put it in the beginning of my Java Script code the carousel stopped turning when clicking on Next or Prev. Now I try to figure out why.

Comment: Check the console output in the F12 tools on your browser (press F12 on your page on windows)

Comment: Thank you, @gaynorvader!
There was a syntax error-I put ; for the loop.
But from the console I saw three more errors.
1. It said that 
    items[i].style("transform", "rotateY(" + (i*increment) + "deg) translateZ(250px)");
was not a function so I changed the code this way
    $(items[i]).css("transform", "rotateY(" + (i*increment) + "deg) translateZ(250px)");
2. ReferenceError: $ is not defined for 
    var carousel = $(".carousel1")
Not sure why.
3. Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/) for 
    function initApplication()
I am reading now what that is.

Comment: And when I tried to delete one of the items from the database so that they rest 5 and not 6, the items on the carousel arrange in a vertical line and when I start  turning them they all turn together as one.
Probably it is because of the missing Tether.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried with the rewritten code. But I still have the same problem if I delete an item from the database-the items then arrange not in a horizontal 3d carousel but in a vertical line which rotates in 3d.
And before I try the code I added 
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

to the head of my layout in Twig and I don't have any more errors in the console.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your code as it is now? Replace any php loops the same way I did in mine. If it works in jsfiddle, the problem my be that your server side code is loading in after the document ready event is fired.

Comment: Ok, have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/qkayvwa9/2/ Play around and you'll see that it works when you add/remove items. (The reason you were having problems is you were adding your external scripts with html tags instead of just a https URL)

Comment: Thank you, @gaynorvader! You are the greatest! It works perfectly now!